# Inconsistency in indent function on xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

the aim of the code is to insert XML chunks into an XML base structure to create the final XML output.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import XMLParser

base_tree     = ET.parse('base_structure_01.XML')
base_root     = base_tree.getroot()

specification = base_tree.find('specification')
applicability = specification.find('applicability')

entity_tree   = ET.parse('entity_structure_01.XML')
entity_root   = entity_tree.getroot()

ET.indent(entity_root,space ="    ",level=3)

applicability.append(entity_root)
base_tree.write('output.xml')
```

Content of base_structure_01.XML :

```
<ids>
    <specification>
        <applicability>
        </applicability>
        <requirements>
        </requirements>
    </specification>
</ids>
```

Content of entity_structure_01.XML :

```
<entity>  
    <name>
        <simpleValue>name</simpleValue>
    </name>
    <predefinedtype>
        <simpleValue>predefinedtype</simpleValue>
    </predefinedtype>
</entity>
```

What I **would like** to be the output :

```
<ids>
    <specification>
        <applicability>
            <entity>
                <name>
                    <simpleValue>name</simpleValue>
                </name>
                <predefinedtype>
                    <simpleValue>predefinedtype</simpleValue>
                </predefinedtype>
            </entity>
        </applicability>
        <requirements>
        </requirements>
    </specification>
</ids>
```

What is currently the output :

```
<ids>
    <specification>
        <applicability>
        <entity>
                <name>
                    <simpleValue>name</simpleValue>
                </name>
                <predefinedtype>
                    <simpleValue>predefinedtype</simpleValue>
                </predefinedtype>
            </entity></applicability>
        <requirements>
        </requirements>
    </specification>
</ids>
```

problems :

- 1st `<entity>` is not correctly indented
- The end `</entity>` is on the same line as `</applicability>`

I know there are other options to indent text, I just wanted to know if with the xml.etree.ElementTree it was possible to solve this easily.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you apply `indent()` on the whole tree, after `append()`.

Replace

```py
ET.indent(entity_root,space ="    ",level=3)

applicability.append(entity_root)
```

with this:

```py
applicability.append(entity_root)

ET.indent(base_root,space ="    ")
```